# Need help in stored procedure view data

Tags: stored-procedures

Somebody please help me by modying this code.when i retrieve the Login value through stored procedure call, i am getting this error message "Procedure or function 'GetUserLogin' expects parameter '@UserName', which was not supplied."
Here is my code:

```
public int GetLogin(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);      
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("GetUserLogin", con);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("GetUserLogin",con);     
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if ((ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString() == UserName) && (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString() == Password))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
StoredProcedure:
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUserLogin @UserName varchar(50)   
AS
select UserName,
       Password
From Login where UserName=@UserName
    RETURN
```

Thanks,
Masum

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a UserName parameter to your command.  Do something like this after you create your command, but before you execute it:

```
com.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
com.Parameters["@UserName"].Value = UserName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this before you fill the dataset

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName",UserName);`

Comment: No you don't, otherwise I'd have a few thousand lines of broken code which are surely not broken.